# listings wrong syntax highlighting in perl - format specification

Tags: listings, highlighting, syntax

Perl uses '#' as an introduction for a comment, but also as a format specification. This produces problems in the syntax highlighting in the listings-package. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=perl,commentstyle=\color{red}}
\begin{lstlisting}
#this is a comment
my $n=89;
#the "@###.####" is NOT a comment
format OUT=
@###.#####                         
$n
.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=perl,morecomment=[l][keywordstyle]{@\#},commentstyle=\color{red}}
\begin{lstlisting}
#this is a comment
my $n=89;
#the "@###.####" is NOT a comment
format OUT=
@###.#####
$n
.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps `basicstyle` should be preferred to `keywordstyle` here.